# Adding custom local fonts to QGIS

Tags: qgis, font

I have some fonts that I want to add to QGIS but not globally to my operating system. So "installing" them e. g. via right-click in Windows or copying them to `/usr/share/fonts/` on Linux is no option for me.

How can I make just QGIS aware of additional fonts?

Answer (score 7):

One approach would be using Qt's [QFontDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont) object which QGIS uses and add fonts to it via Python:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QFontDatabase
qfontdatabase = QFontDatabase()
qfontdatabase.addApplicationFont("/tmp/ChivoMono-SemiBold.ttf")
qfontdatabase.addApplicationFont("/tmp/ComicSans.otf")
```

The font will be available immediately after running the `addApplicationFont` method.

You can use this for example in a plugin or in a [startup.py](https://docs.qgis.org/master/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-python-code-when-qgis-starts) script.